# Не работает код executeemany для вставки в MySQL списка словарей в Python

Tags: mysql

Код выдает ошибку - error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax:

```
PAIR = 'ETH_USD'
def update_mysql():
    try:
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", 
                                    passwd="&&&&&&&&&", db="exmo")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)
    cur = db.cursor()
    resource = requests.get('https://api.exmo.com/v1/trades/? 
                           pair=%s&limit=100' % PAIR)
    data = json.loads(resource.text)
    try:
        data = json.loads(resource.text)
    except ValueError as e:
       print(e)
    list_data = data[PAIR] 
    list_sort=sorted(list_data , key=lambda d: d['date']) #, reverse=True)
#    print(list_data)
#    print(list_sort)
    q =  """insert ignore into trade
                (trade_id, type,quantity,price,amount, date)
                 values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    try:
        cur.prepare(q)
        cur.executemany(q, list_sort)
#        print('Yes')
        db.commit()
        cur.close()
        db.close()
    except:
#        print('No')
        db.rollback()
    return()
```

Comment: перевод: «у вас ошибка в синтаксисе sql». что осталось непонятым?

Comment: Это работает:   for item in reversed(data[PAIR]):
        _SQL = """insert ignore into trade
                  (trade_id, type, amount, quantity, date, price)
                  values
                  (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cur.execute(_SQL, (item['trade_id'],item['type'],item['amount'],item['quantity'],item['date'],item['price']))